# Can't see folders that end with lib in Visual Studio cmake solution

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a cmake project with some sub-folders. When I open it with VS 2019 I can see all the sub-folders except those which end with lib (e.g. MyProj_Lib). I could not find any way to control this filter.
Any idea?

Comment: By "sub-folders" you mean the kind of info set via [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html) command I assume? Or are you referring to info provided via `[CMAKE_]FOLDER` var/target property. Cannot reproduce with `source_group(FILES)` and VS 2022 btw.

Comment: I have a root folder with CMakeLists.txt file and in there are some sub-folders with CMakeLists.txt of their own which are included as add_subdirectory in the main CMakeLists.txt file.